# Entitymanager not persist

Tags: spring, entitymanager

I have problem with entitymanager in my application. It doesn't persist objects to DB
../java/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
 <persistence-unit name="dataSource" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    </persistence-unit>
```

../java/resources/database/DataSource.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>
```

../java/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml

```
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <import resource="classpath:database/DataSource.xml"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>



</beans>
```

What is wrong with it ?

Comment: whether the given code is running under a transaction? is there any exception thrown

Comment: Code is running, no exceptions, but it doesn't persist

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify what is your persistence unit provider. For example:

```
<persistence-unit name="dataSource" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
</persistence-unit>
```

You also need to configure it (eg if Hibernate, what dialects, charset, etc) and add all the required dependencies.

Consider using Spring Roo tool to simplify all these task for you

Comment: How do it without using ejb ?

Comment: The above is just specifying which JPA provider you're using. Not necessarily using EJB (I'm assuming you're imagining EJB 2). JPA and the new EJB 3 is correlated anyway I think.